# Maintain python virtual environment across raku shell commands

Tags: raku

Is there a way to activate a python virtual env in one raku shell command, and then access the env in the next shell command? I want to do something like this in raku. Let's assume there is an executable named "execute_software" under the "some_env" env:

```
shell("source some_env");
shell("execute_software XXX XXX");
shell("source deactivate");
```

Currently, this doesn't work for me.

Thanks!

Tao

Comment: Why not execute all in one: `shell("source some_env; execute_software XXX XXX; source deactivate")` ?

Comment: Thanks! Due to the particular requirement of the software being developed, I strongly prefer to do it separately. Do you think there is a way?

Comment: There might be if you are able to open a pipe to the shell process and keep it alive, see the [run()](https://docs.raku.org/type/Proc#sub_run) command for example. But the current `shell()` command will not work since it will start a new process for each call (and wait for its completion).

Answer (score 3):

I don't know how you expected the environment to stay around after the program exits.
That is not something you can do with anything as far as I'm aware.

If that is something you want, may I suggest using Inline::Python?

```raku
use Inline::Python;
my $py = Inline::Python.new();

$py.run('print("hello world")');

use string:from<Python>;
say string::capwords('foo bar'); # prints "Foo Bar"
```